# How to place separator in between gallery elements

Tags: android

I need to place an separator in between the gallery elements, I have set horizontal scroll menus using gallery, here I to place a separator between gallery elements.

Example design:

```
                ------------------------
                 Games | Music | Movies
                ------------------------
```

I need to place an vertical line between the menus. How can I get it?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563986/how-to-dispaly-separators and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557365/how-to-display-separators It looks like you're doing multi account to ask the same question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need to separate the each item in the `Gallery` view. My Suggestion is to set the frames for each item in the `Gallery`. For that, you can check the ApiDemos/VIew/Gallery/Photos Example. I thought the separator in the Gallery is complicated to implement up to my knowledge.

Comment: @ hi,i need your help on implementing listview with footer,where i got the view as well with footer at bottom,here the problem is where the footer hava click event to parse next page url data to bind on list view,where parsing to be good,but the list being stay back with previous page content,where the newly parsed data is not being added with list view,what is the problem,how can i fix it.just refer my question i posted with layout,i hope you may help me to get what i needed. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Empty view will create the line seperator

Answer (score 0):

You can had "type" to your item and switch on the getView : check for the "type" (custom item with flag maybe) and return the View according to this (View or your separator)